# How to filter the post by search keyword in title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, elementor

Recently I'm working in wordpress blog search. In my site when I'm searching "best" in blogs page. It showing all the post that having that keyword (include title and content). But I need a result, show the post that having the keyword in the title. don't need to check the keyword in the content.

I'm using Post widget using Elementor in Wordpress. in that widget we can customize our query using Query Id.

```
add_action("elementor/query/blogs_search", function ($query) {
$query-\>set("s", htmlentities($\_GET\["s"\]));
}
```

this is the code I'm using for customize query for post using **Query Id - blogs_search**

How to code a query for search that filter the title?

Comment: The point of `s` is to search in title _and_ content. Use `title` instead.

Comment: I done that it not filtering

Comment: I search the Elementor codebase, and did not find any action hook starting with `elementor/query`. Is the Post widget coming from another plugin? Is it [Posts Widget Pro](https://elementor.com/help/posts-widget-pro/)? If so, that’s a premium plugin, so may be awhile before someone with access to or experience with the plugin can help.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

Comment: this code won't work for my url structure **/blogs/search?s=help**

Comment: This is for adjusting WordPress’ search, not the Elementor widget’s search.